# Why JOIN LATERAL doesn't unpivot multiple fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I am very new to postgresql and would really appreciate any help. I am currently using this script (it works fine):

```
 FROM dataset as d
    
    LEFT JOIN metric m on d.datasetid=m.datasetid
    LEFT JOIN value v on m.metricid=v.metricid
    LEFT JOIN submetric_1 s1 ON v.submetric_1id=s1.submetric_1id
    LEFT JOIN submetric_2 s2 ON v.submetric_2id=s2.submetric_2id
    LEFT JOIN year y on v.valueid=y.valueid
    LEFT JOIN quarter q on v.valueid=q.valueid
    LEFT JOIN country c on v.valueid=c.valueid
    LEFT JOIN region r on v.valueid=r.valueid
    LEFT JOIN county co on v.valueid=co.valueid
    LEFT JOIN ladistrict l on v.valueid=l.valueid
```

This script returns columns from SELECT clause as follows:

metric  value   […] country region  county  ladistrict

I need to unpivot four last geographical columns  'country','region','county' and 'ladistrict' to get a return as follows:

metric  value   […]   Geography  Geography name

```
                   Country    Country name  
                   Region     Region name   
                   County     County name   
                   Ladistrict Ladistrict name
```

I am trying LATERAL clause as follows:

```
FROM dataset as d

LEFT JOIN metric m on d.datasetid=m.datasetid
LEFT JOIN value v on m.metricid=v.metricid
LEFT JOIN submetric_1 s1 ON v.submetric_1id=s1.submetric_1id
LEFT JOIN submetric_2 s2 ON v.submetric_2id=s2.submetric_2id
LEFT JOIN year y on v.valueid=y.valueid
LEFT JOIN quarter q on v.valueid=q.valueid

LEFT JOIN LATERAL (VALUES
      ('Country',c.country)
      ,('Ladistrict', l.ladistrict)
      ,('Region', r.region)
      , ('County',co.county))
      s (Geography, geo_name)
```

And this one returns error. Please, any ideas how to make it work and get these fields unpivoted? Thanks

Comment: Please Add sample output of first query and desired output

Answer (score 0):

A left join needs a join condition.  It could be as simple as`ON TRUE`.  However, it's easier to just change that left join lateral to a cross join lateral.